# Synchronizing threads to send and receive data from arduino

Tags: java, arduino

I'm creating a method to send and receive data from arduino . After I call this method in a thread. I use ThreadPoolExecutor to execute this thread 3 times.Because I have 3 JtestField and I need in every one show a received data. when I execute them only one which ise shown. I was trying to use differe t methods to synchronize these threads but no result. Thank you for your help.

This is the method:

```
  synchronized  void sendReceive(String txt,JTextField txt_){
        PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(OpenPort.getPort().getOutputStream());
        cr=txt;
        output.print(cr);
        output.flush();

        OpenPort.getPort().addDataListener(new SerialPortDataListener() {
               @Override
               public int getListeningEvents() { return SerialPort.LISTENING_EVENT_DATA_AVAILABLE; }
               @Override
               public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
               {

                    Scanner data=new Scanner(OpenPort.getPort().getInputStream());



                    while(data.hasNextLine()) {
                            String msg = null;
                            Object item=null;
                            try{msg= data.nextLine();}catch(Exception e){}

                            if(msg != null) {


                                txt_.setText(msg);
                                list.add(msg);
                                System.out.println(list);
                                System.out.println(item);


                            }
                            msg = null;


                    }

               }

        });
   }
```

The thread in which I call it:

```
      class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
    String cr=null;
    JTextField txt_;
    String txt;
    private Thread t;
    ThreadDemo(String txt,JTextField txt_) {
          this.txt = txt;
          this.txt_ = txt_;
       }

        @Override
        public void run() {

              sendReceive(txt,txt_);
              try {Thread.sleep(1000000);} catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
        }




    }
```

and after I use the ThreadPoolExecutor to execte threads in the constructor of my first class:

```
   //ip                 
 executor.execute(new ThreadDemo("ee_get:100",SCAN.ipAddress_txt));

//port
 executor.execute(new ThreadDemo("ee_get:160",SCAN.port_txt));

 //intervale
 executor.execute(new ThreadDemo("ee_get:60",SCAN.intervale_txt));

 executor.shutdown();
```

please any help I was spending a lot of time to resolve this problem and no result.

Normally I must send 3 commands to arduino and receive 3 times data and every time this data must be shown in a JTextField. However I see one received data in the JTextfield

Comment: Not a big expert in Java, but using synchronized in the function (and assuming it's the same object), means that only one thread will be able to execute sendReceive(). Therefore, what's the point in running 3 threads? In addition, have you confirmed that the first thread finishes the task and exits the function? (If it does not, then the other threads will not be able to execute).

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer but how can I add that in my code:" have you confirmed that the first thread finishes the task and exits the function" I tried to do that but I failed

Comment: This is the link for my project code source https://github.com/omayma9/SerialPort.git If someone could help me

Comment: I guess my question is: why are you doing a threads and thread pool? why not serialize it? (run one by one). What are you looking to gain? It looks like you're setting up 3 threads to read from the same input stream, that may potentially be problematic.

Comment: I want to read from the same input stream 3 times and show received data one by one in a JTextField (I have 3 JTextfield). I was using one thread but whene I call the thread 3 times I receive one time.

Comment: I tried to run one by one but I failed